# Are there any small peptides with protease activity?

Tags: enzymes, protein-engineering

I'm looking for a very small protease to base an engineered protein on.  I did a search for "peptides with protease activity" but all the results seem to be as peptides to be used as protease *substrates* (eg in assays); I couldn't find any catalytic peptides.

What is the smallest protease or domain which has independent proteolytic activity?  (Ideally looking for something very short, a dozen aminoacids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60 residues is the smallest I could find, ref below.

https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1423-0127-19-54

Comment: feel free to edit answer for style